# How to insert into Sqlite with optional parameters using Swift 3

Tags: swift3, sqlite.swift

I have this class with some optional properties:

```
class Address {
    var Id: Int64
    var AddressType: Int64
    var AddressStatus: Int64
    var Address1: String?
    var Address2: String?
    var City: String?
    var State: String?
    var Zip: String?
    var Country: String?
    var Latitude: Double?
    var Longitude: Double?
}
```

I am trying to insert into a Sqlite database, like this:

```
let insert = table.insert(or: .replace, Id <- item.Id, AddressType <- item.AddressType, AddressStatus <- item.AddressStatus, Address1 <- item.Address1?, Address2 <- item.Address2?, City <- item.City?, State <- item.State?, Zip <- item.Zip?, Country <- item.Country?, Latitude <- item.Latitude?, Longitude <- item.Longitude?)
```

But I get this build error:

```
Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

If I use '!' it will build, but I get this error when I run:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I am still new to Swift, but from what I know, I don't want to use '!' when the value can be nil, correct?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all your class properties constants (declare with let) and make them non optional adding a required init() with all your Address properties parameters. BTW it is Swift convention to start your vars naming with a lowercase letter. Note: You should use Int instead of Int64 unless it is a requirement. Regarding the optionality of your properties you can just assign a default value for them at initialization time. Btw It is better to use a struct unless you need to make your object persist (NSCoding compliant):

```
struct Address {
    let id: Int
    let addressType: Int
    let addressStatus: Int
    let address1: String
    let address2: String
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let zip: String
    let country: String
    let latitude: Double?
    let longitude: Double?
    init(id: Int, addressType: Int, addressStatus: Int, address1: String = "", address2: String = "", city: String = "", state: String = "", zip: String = "", country: String = "", latitude: Double = nil, longitude: Double = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.addressType = addressStatus
        self.addressStatus = addressStatus
        self.address1 = address1
        self.address2 = address2
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip = zip
        self.country = country
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

---

So you can create your new object Address as follow:

```
let address1 = Address(id: 1, addressType: 2, addressStatus: 3)
let address2 = Address(id: 2, addressType: 3, addressStatus: 4, address1: "Any Address", latitude: 22.0, longitude: 43.0)   // You don't need to add all parameters as long as you keep them in the same order as your initializer

address2.latitude   // 22.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. BTW, my properties are capitalized only because I am keeping it consistent with the properties from a web API I am calling. Thanks again!!

Comment: BTW, my "Address" class actually inherits from anther class "BaseEntity" and that is why I was using class instead of struct. When I try struct, it gives an error about "inheritance from non-protocol type..."

Comment: And one last thing.. your example above doesn't have any "?" in the init.. however the only way I saw to allow a nil date is to do "created: Date? = nil"   is this correct?  Everything else made perfect sense to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you can do that to optionals also to make it an optional initializer parameter. You can see the same behavior when using the DateComponents initializer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134095/discussion-between-primico-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @LeoDabus. I know you're struggling to collect points :) ..  you may want this bounty man!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874682/subtle-cast-warning-when-using-sqlite-swift-binding-to-any  Damned if I can figure it out...